# decipher bash extended regular expression

Tags: regex, bash

I've got an input data, which follows the format below (it's all 1 line):

> {"auth": "15a63c4:e66189ba", "createdAt": "2013-05-12T00:00:01-08:00",
>   "payload": {"itemId"": "15607", "marker": 240}, "refId": "47c7e2f6",
>   "sessionID": "82ada851-0b3c-4e9d-b8cf-0f0a2ebed278", "type": "Play",
>   "user": 22700996, "userAgent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0;
>   Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.1)"}

I've got a grep command with a quirky regular expression:

```
grep -Eo "\"$1\": [^,]+" | cut -d: -f2- | tr -d '" '
```

I suspect (not completely sure & having hard time checking) that it returns this:

> "type": "Play"

Could you **please** explain (break it down and explain) this hell of the command and regular expression to me bit by bit?

I've spent about 40 mins with all the internet reference material but ain't got any closer to understanding what exactly that grep does :(

**Edit**: the input argument to the script is "type", so $1 stands for "type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down the pipeline:

```
grep -Eo "\"$1\": [^,]+"
```

This searches the input text for a literal double quote (escaped with the backslash), followed by the value of `$1` (ie the first parameter passed to the script/function containing this command), another literal double quote, a literal space, then one or more characters which are not a comma. If `$1` is `type`, the result of this will be `"type": "Play"`.

```
cut -d: -f2-
```

This uses a colon as the delimiter for `cut`, and prints out the second and subsequent fields of the input. Continuing the example, the result will be `"Play"` (note that the space is still there).

```
tr -d '" '
```

The `-d` option for `tr` effectively means "delete" - so all double quotes and spaces are deleted. The result is now `Play`.

The intention seems to be that you pass a key as the first parameter of the script/function, and the corresponding value is returned.

Answer (score 1):

That's not merely a regular expression, it's a string containing variable interpolation.  Whatever `$1` is set to in Bash will be included in the regex.  But apparently, the intent is to call it with something like `type` in `$1` and extract the value of `type` (i.e. `Play`) from the JSONish fragment.

```
xtract () {
    grep -Eo "\"$1\": [^,]+" | cut -d: -f2- | tr -d '" '
}

xtract "type" <<'HERE'
{"auth": "15a63c4:e66189ba", "createdAt": "2013-05-12T00:00:01-08:00",
 "payload": {"itemId"": "15607", "marker": 240}, "refId": "47c7e2f6",
 "sessionID": "82ada851-0b3c-4e9d-b8cf-0f0a2ebed278", "type": "Play",
 "user": 22700996, "userAgent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; etc etc)"}
HERE
```

Output:

```
Play
```

So you see, you can pass a key as an argument to the function `xtract` and it will extract the value of that key (provided the input is reasonably well-formed, which is true here<sup>1</sup> but a recipe for failure in the grand scheme of things).

<sup>1</sup>  Well, not really; the `itemId` has two double quotes after the key.
  So with this particular example input, you can't `xtract itemId` (but if you know what the problem is, you can cheat and `xtract 'itemId"'`!)

The regex looks for the key in double quotes, followed by anything which is not a comma.  It will extract everything after the colon, and remove any double quotes and spaces from that.

A somewhat more correct solution would not break on values containing a comma inside double quotes, or squash spaces in values; if the input was proper JSON, a dedicated JSON tool such as [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) would be vastly preferable to an ad-hoc parser using regular expressions.

```
$ jq -r '.type' <<'HERE'
{"auth": "15a63c4:e66189ba", "createdAt": "2013-05-12T00:00:01-08:00",
 "payload": {"itemId": "15607", "marker": 240}, "refId": "47c7e2f6",
 "sessionID": "82ada851-0b3c-4e9d-b8cf-0f0a2ebed278", "type": "Play",
 "user": 22700996, "userAgent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; etc etc)"}
HERE
Play
```

(Again, notice that this requires properly-formatted JSON input.)

Comment: Thank you! I've edited the question including the value of the $1, it turns out to be "type"

Comment: Thanks again!! Everything is very clear to me now :)

Comment: @tripleee i think you could further reduce the grep command like, `grep -oP "\"$1\": \"?\K[^\",]+"`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yeah, I thought about that, but really, `jq` is the proper way to go (especially if the double double quotes are just an isolated transcription mistake)

Answer (score 0):

- `grep -Eo "\"$1\": [^,]+"`
  Here am assuming $1 as type. This command will give you string from "type till it matches first comma. So here your output would be

  ```
  "type": "Play"
  ```
- cut -d: -f2-
  Output of grep Command is input to cut command which splits the file with : (colon) as delimiter and outputs field 2 onwards any string which will output

  ```
  "Play"
  ```
- tr -d '" '
  This command will take input from cut command and will delete all the space and double quotes from the string that it recieved from cut command. So the output would be

  ```
  Play
  ```